# Make Http Request to Api and Convert to json

Tags: c#, request, dotnet-httpclient

My question may be trivial but I have spent almost 6hrs just trying things out.

```
public async Task<object> save() 
{
    var uri = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=talksport&apiKey=longKey";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient ();
    HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    var data = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    // this is what I want to achieve like in python you can do something like this
    foreach(var item in data){
        Console.writeline(item.summary);
    }
    // end of arbitrary code
    return data;
}
```

My problem is ,am unable to do this conversion to get the response and then accessing the json data. 
In python you can do something

```
r = request.get(apiUrl)
data = r.json()
for item in data:
   print(item.summary)
```

This is all I have struggle to achieve with c#, Any help to complete the code or explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

Install [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.3) package and add `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage()) {
    request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=talksport&apiKey=longKey");
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;

    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request)) {
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<dynamic>>(content);

        foreach(var item in result){
           Console.writeline(item.summary);
        }
    }
}
```

From comment

> Then i get this
>   "{\"vouchers\":[\"UN9NKK\",\"FYMFVS\",\"WV5AX7\",\"M2TJJ8\",‌​\"FBB9AL\",\"MBW8Z4\‌​"]}"

You can create a new class

```
public class MyResponse { 
   public IEnumerable<string> Vouchers {get;set; } 
}
```

then

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(content); 
foreach(var item in response.Vouchers){
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and i got this error.. JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize

Comment: It actually breaks on Deserialization line

Comment: Ok, What is the expected response? As I see from your code you expect Json with array of objects

Comment: object.. But when I `readStringAsync` convert the response to string. Then i get this `"{\"vouchers\":[\"UN9NKK\",\"FYMFVS\",\"WV5AX7\",\"M2TJJ8\",\"FBB9AL\",\"MBW8Z4\"]}"
` with escape characters, so the Deserialization fails  in parsing the escape characters...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a small library dependency, [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) (disclaimer: I'm the author) gets you Python's simplicity in C#:

```
var data = await apiUrl.GetJsonAsync();
```

In this case, `data` is a C# [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) type, which means you can access all the JSON object's properties by name without defining a corresponding C# class, much like an untyped language. If you do want to declare a class and get compile-time type checking, that works with Flurl too:

```
var data = await apiUrl.GetJsonAsync<MyClass>();
```

Now `data` is an instance of `MyClass` instead of a dynamic.

[Get Flurl.Http on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/), and reference it with `using Flurl.Http;`.